# React.js - observable states like observable in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In ember I could write something like this:

```
statusChanged(){
//...do some code
}.observes('observableProperty')
```

What is the right way to do the similar work in React.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do your logic in component lifecycle methods
`componentWillMount`, `componentWillReceiveProps` and others.
Whenever you pass new props to a component it will run throutg lifecycle.
[Read more about it](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html)

Alternatively you can use [Rx.js](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS). But conceptually I dont think it is a correct approach. React implies you to manipulate props and states of a component and handle all logic in lifecycle or in synthetic events.